# UITableView scroll similar to Frontback app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have UITableView and each cell occupies whole screen. Do you have any tips how could I implement scrolling as it can be seen in Frontback app? http://frontback.me

So when user scrolls up, it goes one whole cell up and it stops.

Thank you?

Comment: maybe defining the cell in same size as the screen's actual size and set the `pagingEnabled` property?

Answer (score 0):

UITableViews make use of a UIScrollView for scrolling, so you can implement the UIScrollViewDelegate methods to achieve this. The method you're looking for is [`scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewWillEndDragging%3awithVelocity%3atargetContentOffset%3a). You can change the targetContentOffset to change where the scroll view end scrolling.